# Alfresco : How can I get file from Sites/test/documentLibrary dynamically?

Tags: javascript, alfresco, alfresco-webscripts

I am uploading an Alfresco file, I need get the file from `documentLibrary` dynamically, how can I do this? .bpm20.xml is possible.

```
 var dest= companyhome.childByNamePath("Sites/test/documentLibrary/"+${trainername});
     bpm_package.addNode(dest);
```

Please help out

Comment: What do you mean "get the file from the document library"? What isn't working with the code you've written?

Comment: now file we have mention statically, i have written Java class from the class i upload file to alfresco documentary library ,  i need same file name i need attach to workflow , i don't how get dynamically file name ,please help on this

Comment: Do you want to start the workflow while uploading the document into document library ? If so, you can rules, correct?

Comment: After created workflow i have to attach document

Answer (score 2):

The `companyhome` is one of [`root objects`](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.1/references/API-JS-rootscoped.html), class [`org.alfresco.repo.jscript.ScriptNode`](http://dev.alfresco.com/resource/docs/java/org/alfresco/repo/jscript/ScriptNode.html).

Method [`ScriptNode.childByNamePath(String path)`](http://dev.alfresco.com/resource/docs/java/org/alfresco/repo/jscript/ScriptNode.html#childByNamePath-java.lang.String-) returns another `ScriptNode`.

To get file name you can use [`ScriptNode.getName()`](http://dev.alfresco.com/resource/docs/java/org/alfresco/repo/jscript/ScriptNode.html#getName--) method (Java or JavaScript) or [`name` property](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.1/references/API-JS-ScriptNode.html) (shortcut access to the `cm:name` property) in JavaScript.

```
var dest= companyhome.childByNamePath("Sites/test/documentLibrary/"+${trainername});
bpm_package.addNode(dest);
logger.info("and the file name is.... "+dest.name);
```

Is that answers your question?

BTW: ["What's the difference between JavaScript and Java?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245062/whats-the-difference-between-javascript-and-java)

Comment: No, Actually my problem is auto generated document attach to workflow